# type or namespace name 'IBehavior' could not be found on TFS Build Server

Tags: windows-store-apps, tfsbuild, build-server

I'm currently working on a Windows 8.1 Store application.

In my development environment, the solution builds successfully. But when the solution is built on a TFS Build Server, it fails with messages :

```
behaviors\MultiSelectBehaviorBase.cs (1): The type or namespace name 'Xaml' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 

behaviors\MultiSelectBehaviorBase.cs (28): The type or namespace name 'IBehavior' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Note that my project references the Windows Extensions : "Behaviors SDK (XAML)" (Version 12.0). I followed tutorial [TFS Continuous Integration for Windows 8.1 Store Apps with SDK dependencies](https://cmatskas.com/tfs-continuous-integration-for-windows-8-1-store-apps-with-sdk-dependencies/).

Without MultiSelectBehaviorBase.cs, it build correctly on TFS Server (even if the project has reference to BehaviorSDK).

MultiSelectBehaviorBase.cs (copied from [Managing Multiple selection in View Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412417/Managing-Multiple-selection-in-View-Model-NET-Metr)) :

```
public class MultiSelectBehaviorBase<T>: DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted some months ago, I had a similar problem "The type or namespace 'IBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly)". Most at times when this kind of errors happens, they are due to an omission of a reference. To solve this problem, I got this information from http://julmar.com/blog/programming/behaviors-in-windows-8-1-store-apps/

Under your project in the solution explorer, double click reference and enable the behavioural SDK as demonstrated on the image below[Behavioural SDK demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShYCo.png)
Note there are instances when such reference can not be found there, you can attempt to download from NuGet Package Manager. I hope this helps.